# Django CMS plugin context vs. page context

Tags: django, django-cms

I have a page for news, and in the `news.detailpage`, I have another 4 items (news, videos, etc) in a small column as cms_plugin's of a model called `CrossItems`.

[image]

The thing is, the context of cms_plugin can have the news which is shown in `news.detailpage`.

My concern is, I don't have access to pages context from cms_plugins context, otherwise I could easily filter out the news.

Is there any way to achieve this, so that the 4 items don't contain the actual news which is shown left?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about something like this..

In your **cms_plugins.py**

If you want the current_page:

```
def render(self, context, instance, placeholder):
    context = super(CrossItemsPlugin, self).render(context, instance, placeholder)
    request = context['request']
    page = request.current_page

   # your logic goes here
```

If you want the current 'article'... you'll need to set it in your views.py

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(NewsDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    setattr(self.request, 'current_article', self.object)
    return context
```

And you could access that in the plugin render method.

```
def render(self, context, instance, placeholder):
    context = super(CrossItemsPlugin, self).render(context, instance, placeholder)
    request = context['request']
    article = request.current_article
```

Comment: oh, ``request.current_page`` gives me the current page context?